# Where to put assignment statement

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

when you open a new file, it opens a new view.
I need to put an assignment statment that references this new view upon opening a file. Where might that be?

It can't be OnOpenDocument because a view is not loaded at that point.

EDIT:
Sorry this is MFC.

Comment: Please provide more context. Re-read your question from the perspective of someone with no prior knowledge about your work - we have no idea what a "view" or `OnOpenDocument` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the best place would be in your derived [CView::OnInitialUpdate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc7fw3a0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cabdh52.aspx) gives the sequence of actions when a new document is opened]